# Should a String be defined static as String literal gets space in String constant pool only once

Tags: java

We declare member variables as static in Java for memory efficiency because static variables get memory only once in the class area.
But for a String variable, should it be declared as static for memory efficiency, as String only gets memory in String Constant Pool.

Comment: Variables should only be defined as static if you want one, and only one, value to be stored for all instances of the class in question.   If you can have multiple instances of a class and each should have its own value in a variable, then that variable *cannot* be static.

Comment: "We declare instance variables as static in Java" - Umm, no, instance variables are, by definition, not static... We rarely declare members as static for efficiency. We declare static members because it makes for them to be static.

Comment: no, "String only gets memory in String Constant Pool" - that is only true for literals (Constant) and interned ([`intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern())) strings

Comment: static fields are used when we only need a value that may be shared to the instances' s class, and not for optimisation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instance variables are different from class variables (static variables).  We call it instance because we access them by creating an instance of the class.

Coming to static variables, we create them if we want them to available during the application load and through out the application and they are available in memory until jvm is stopped.

Coming to your scenario, if you want to retain the string value (some thing like Logger) and use the same value throughout the application you can create it as a static variable. But if you think the value of the String may change for each instance then it is better to have as an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

To the question of "will declaring a string static/non-static save memory space?"

You are correct about how String constants are placed in the String constants memory section. Strings created dynamically (i.e. at runtime) will still be put in the heap.

Using static you will theoretically save space in memory on the heap, because there will be only one pointer / reference to your string - the static one. But in terms of memory management, even an instantiated basic `Object` is 50+ bytes. Then there's the issue of memory partitioning... Your saving 4/6 bytes may not be saving any / much space at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?